# Creating a batch file with options

Tags: batch-file

I have reviewed the current posts about this subject and have tried the various suggestions for creating the batch file. This is what I have come up with so far. However, the batch file seems to want to only run Copy to Laptop, regardless of the choice selected. Please help!

```
@ECHO OFF

CLS

ECHO 1.Copy to Desktop?

ECHO 2.Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive?

ECHO 3.Copy to Laptop?

ECHO 4.Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive?

ECHO.


CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Enter your Choice:"


IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive?

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO Copy to Laptop?

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive?

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Copy to Desktop?



:Copy to Laptop?

ECHO Copy to Laptop 

xcopy H:\ "C:\Users\8888\Documents\My Games" /e /y

GOTO End


:Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive?

ECHO Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive 

xcopy "C:\Users\8888\Documents\My Games" H:\ /e /y

GOTO End


:Copy to Desktop?

ECHO Copy to Desktop 

xcopy H:\ "C:\Users\****\Documents\My Games" /e /y

GOTO End


:Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive?

ECHO Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive 

xcopy "C:\Users\****\Documents\My Games" H:\ /e /y

GOTO End

:End
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that all of the labels are using only the first word, which in all cases is `COPY` (the first space seems to be where it stops looking at the label).

This works perfectly fine for me. Notice that I've changed all of the `:Label` names to something still meaningful by removing the spaces and the `?` at the end. (I also removed the `xcopy` lines, because they weren't necessary to demonstrate the solution.)

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1.Copy to Desktop?

ECHO 2.Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive?

ECHO 3.Copy to Laptop?

ECHO 4.Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive?

ECHO.

CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Enter your Choice:"

IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO LapTopToFlashDrive
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO CopyToLaptop
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO DesktopToFlashDrive
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO CopyToDesktop

:CopyToLaptop

ECHO Copy to Laptop 
GOTO End


:LaptopToFlashDrive

ECHO Copy FROM Laptop to Flash Drive 
GOTO End


:CopyToDesktop
ECHO Copy to Desktop 
GOTO End

:DesktopToFlashDrive
ECHO Copy FROM Desktop to Flash Drive 
GOTO End

:End
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not allowed in GOTO statements.
So all your GOTOs goes to the first `:Copy`. The rest "to Desktop?" and so on is ignored.